# Is a self-answered question appropriate in this case?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering about the specific mechanics of a Diablo 3 item, and decided to ask a question about it. When checking if the question had already been answered (SE search, Ask Question -> type in title and see suggestions, and lastly a google search), the google search led me to the answer in some Reddit discussion.

What should I do in this case? Should I post the question I originally had in mind along with the answer I found, to improve the "completeness" of Arqade?

Reading on this issue, I found that the consensus  is that [self-answering is encouraged](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5670/asking-a-question-to-which-you-already-know-the-answer), as it helps promote the site and presents the information to people in a nice easy-to-read manner. However, I feel like it borders on plagiarism, as the answer is relatively easy to find through Google.

The Reddit source can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/3c9p8i/obsidian_ring_of_the_zodiac_how_does_it_work/), for the particular question I had in mind.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, self answering is perfectly fine in this case.

Make sure you have a proper link to the source and you'll be fine. The question surely isn't the first to be solved by a google search.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the previous answer, it is perfectly fine if you add questions and answers you were wondering yourself. However, when you are going to search other sites for possible questions, and spam them here, that would be unwanted.